# Maximize application with two opened form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two form in my application
first form is used the background and sec form showed on the first form with this code:

```
frsform _frsform=new frsform();     
_frsform.TopLevel = true;
_frsform.ShowInTaskbar = false;
_frsform.ShowDialog();
```

I use this code to minimized both opened form

```
 foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
 {
   frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
 }
```

but when i click on task bar for maximize my application the second form is hidden and i just see first form.

what do i must do for see both forms when i maximize application?(see first form behind sec form)

Comment: is your first form is MDI form ?

Comment: @Neeraj Kumar Gupta:no and i don't wat to use MDI Form

Comment: Dialogs should *never* be minimized.  Use the Show(owner) overload instead, passing the 'background' form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Showing "_frsform" as an dialog over main form. When you minimize "_frsform" closing itself. So better use "Show" instead of "Showdialog".

Answer (score 1):

Below will trap the event on your first form when you resize and allow you to then make the required adjustments to the second form:

```
   private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximised)

       {
              // add code here to show second form

       }
   }
```